# Visual Studio Code (Emmet): Add closing tag comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

So I would like Visual Studio Code (with the aid of Emmet) to be able to transform something like

```
.wrapper
```

into this

```
<div class="wrapper"></div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

I believe there are solutions for how to do this in Sublime Text and Webstorm, so it would be great to know if there is one for Visual Studio Code as well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know you can just add `|c` to the end of your .wrapper to get a comment added at the end like:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<!-- /.wrapper -->
```

Infortunately, that puts the trailing comment on a newline.  If that is unacceptable, see [remove line break before comment](http://iaintnoextra.tumblr.com/post/68089741466/automatically-add-closing-comments-to-html-using)  and see [emmet comment filter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_comment-filter-c) for modifying the filer for comments in vscode.

And put this into your settings.json:

```
"emmet.preferences": {
    "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->"
}
```

I just removed the newline \n from the example comment filter.

Alternatively, it can be done pretty easily with a snippet (in your html.json snippets file):

```
"emmet with comment": {
    "prefix": ".",
    "body": [
        "<div class='$1'>$2</div><!-- /.$1 -->"
    ],
    "description": "expand with comment"
}
```

Then type the <kbd>.</kbd> and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and type your classname, it will go into both $1's.  <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to get to the $2 cursor location.  [You may have to hit <kbd>escape</kbd> if you get suggestions after you type your classname.]

To use the tab completion, change this in your settings:

```
  // When enabled, Emmet abbreviations are expanded when pressing TAB.
 "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false,
```

to true.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a heap!

Comment: `"emmet with comment": {
    "prefix": ".",
    "body": [
        "<div class='$1'>$2</div><!-- /.$1 -->"
    ],
    "description": "expand with comment"
}` doesn't seem to work any longer

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried the snippet, still works.  Make sure you are selecting the right snippet in the suggestions box.

Answer (score 2):

To get Emmet to add comments and keep them on the same line as the closing tag, add the following to your user settings file in Visual Studio Code, and then restart VSC.

```
 "emmet.preferences":{
    "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->",
  },
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  // Enable XHTML dialect for HTML syntax
  // “html”: “xhtml”
    "html" : {
      "filters" :"html, c"
      }
  },
```